# Security Of Dynamic Loaded DLL

Tags: c++

I want to design a simple security system via rolling code by system time in a dll file. DLL will have only one exported function like "bool result()" so will return true or false to my main application when called. DLL will loaded dynamically to main application with "LoadLibrary(...)" method and its function will call after.

But I don't have any knowledge on hacking and code security.

That's  the question: Can the hacker see what I'm doing inside DLL function especially what operation performed to decide the result, or can he change what result i'm returning from dynamically loaded dll?

Comment: if a hacker has already compromised the system, your whole operating system could conceivably be running in a virtual machine, with every operation, every keypress and every bit of network traffic being readable / under control of the hacker, without you, the operating system etc. being aware of the fact. There is very little you can do to ensure safety on a compromised system (i.e. with the hacker already being "on" your system).

Comment: "I don't have any knowledge on hacking and code security" - this means that it's highly unlikely that whatever you're doing is going to be effective. I have no idea what "a simple security system via rolling code by system time" even means. Perhaps you should outline what *threats* you're attempting to protect against and what scenario you're working in. However, at that point, I'm not sure SO would still be an on-topic area. [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) may be better - but you need to describe your *problem*, not your proposed *solution*.

Comment: This is just a control application of our company's product, it will sell customers to control their products. I mean "simple" as not as "secure like bank application", if just an nerd cannot hack system easily is enough for us.

Comment: If this is licensing related, you're really heading out in the wrong direction. The hacker doesn't need to understand what the DLL does. They can just edit the main executable so that instead of calling into the DLL, they just pretend that it did and returned `true`. If you want licensing enforcement, I'd strongly suggest buying a component to do it - it's not your area of expertise, you're unlikely to get it right. Added to which, it *will* impact your legitimate customers and your product will *still* be hacked if people decide it's valuable enough to do so.

Answer (score 4):

In order to understand and write good shared libraries, it is  important that you go though how loader and elf format interact.

The article that I found really helpful is Ulrich Depper's:

http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

It provides really good insight into how shared libraries are loaded, how to control the visibility of symbols, optimizations and others. It is a pretty vast topic in itself and will take some time to understand, but it's worth it.

If you are into data structures and such stuff, there are even explanations on how bloom filters, hash table and others are used for lookup purposes.

> Can the hacker see what I'm doing inside DLL function especially what
>   operation performed to decide the result

He can only see symbols that are exported by you.
There are many ways of hiding/exporting symbols.
Ex:  `__attribute__((visibility(hidden)))`

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

> can he change what result i'm returning from dynamically loaded dll?

If the input that is given to api's exposed via shared library is handled correctly (check for buffer overrun, etc) in implementation, it should be fine I guess. The user has control over the input that is provided to API and that influences output. If I have missed something here, it would be great if someone can correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Outsider can see the all exported function signatures (You can use depWalker and try). But they cant see the implementation inside (As I know). if you just return true, outsiders also possible to create their own DLL with same function, that returns true.

May be instead you can return a dynamically generated code instead just true or false, and you can validate the code in the main exe after loading the DLL.

There is another way to export functions in the DLL using the sequence number, not the signature using *.def files. May be have a look about that.

Comment: "if you just return true, outsiders also possible to create their own DLL with same function, that returns true."  nice point, I will change return type.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question...

basically a hacker can't see what you are doing inside your DLL because the DLL is loaded into the application and the application's Memory is protected (See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366785(v=vs.85).aspx))

The more important Thing here is if your result you are returning can be **predicted** e.g. if you are using random numbers, are they predictable? (You can read more about this [here](https://www.random.org/randomness/))

Answer (score 0):

He can, of course. Especially if your DLL is small in size.